# Is there a Great Plains merge web service API for customer records?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-gp

Has anyone found a good web service API for merging customer records in Great Plains? My company has a custom ASP.NET eCommerce application which processes credit card transactions then integrates invoices to GP for fulfillment. The custom eCommerce application supports merging accounts when there are multiple per person. However, Great Plains (and eConnect) don't provide an web service for reflecting the merge in Great Plains.

I'd like to avoid rolling my own and hope there is a product available that merges customer records and all associated historic data.